# mongo ObjectId.fromDate using a variable

Tags: bash, mongodb

I need to create an ObjectId.fromDate that will always be 65 days past.

```
d=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S --date "-65 days")
object=$(mongo --quiet --eval 'ObjectId.fromDate(ISODate("$d"))')
```

but I'm getting:

```
# echo $object
2017-04-28T10:47:39.810+0300 E QUERY [thread1] Error: invalid ISO date 
: ISODate@src/mongo/shell/types.js:65:1 @(shell eval):1:19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using single quotes, so `$d` is not being substituted in the bash string.

```
object=$(mongo --quiet --eval "ObjectId.fromDate(ISODate('$d'))")
```

does the job.